# MagentoAPI in C# catalogProductRequestAttributes

Tags: c#, magento

I'm trying to retrieve product information from magento by calling its web service using c#.
so far i'm getting all of the product information correctly except custom attributes like shirt_size, color, etc

I wanna get shirt_size in term of string, such as 'Medium', 'Large','XXS', etc
However when i call  catalogProductInfo with additional attributes attached

```
 //attribute
                var attributes = new catalogProductRequestAttributes
                                                                 {
                                                                     attributes =
                                                                         new string[] { "name", "description", "price" },
                                                                     additional_attributes = new string[] { "shirt_size","gender","color" }
                                                                 };


 catalogProductReturnEntity productReturnEntity =
                        magentoService.catalogProductInfo(sessionId, product.sku, null, attributes, null);
```

I only get associativeEntity with key="shirt_size", value="100", another one key="gender", value="36"

Does that mean i have to use another method to look up value of that associativeEnity value to get string such as "Medium", "Large", "male" , etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var attribute = magentoService.catalogProductAttributeOptions(sessionId, "shirt_size", null);

then it will return catalogAttributeOptionEntity
with Label="Small", value="100" information